# Submit python code with Livy

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, livy

how I can submit a code pyspark with Livy?
I used this and it works

```
curl localhost:8998/sessions/0/statements -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"code":"srdd.get(\"ak\")"}'
```

But now i would to pass a command, example this

```
curl localhost:8998/sessions/69/statements -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d  '{“code”: textwrap.dedent("""
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
B = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM A")
B.collect()”””
}'
```

but there is syntax error...
Who know the just right for write this command?

Thanks

Thank you

Comment: Simplest solution would be to put the code snippet in file and pass data as location of file instead of code snippet directly...like .. `-d  '{"file": "file:/tmp/test.py", "name": "Livy PySpark Example"}"`

Comment: I found a solution, but your solution is nice! Tks